# How to update database with Netbeans GUI?

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface, netbeans

I have a basic GUI ready and I have a database that I would like to use to put data into using the GUI. 
[image: GUI]

I have been searching the web for quite a few days but there is no straightforward description on how to put data into the database using the GUI I created. I am a noob in Java so could somebody please direct me to a decent tutorial or tell me of a book in which there is a good tutorial to do so. My database is in MySQL and the connection has been completed successfully. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll brief you how to do it. Then its upto you how you implement it.

As I can see your form, there is a `submit` button. You have to write the code on its `actionListener` which is called when the button is clicked.

Steps to Write into database : 

1. Find suitable connector as per your Database and include it in your build path.

2. In `actionListner`

- Obtain a connection by passing URL, Username and Password of the database.
- Create `Statement` object which execute your query. You can better go for `PreparedStatement`.
- Write appropriate query and execute it.

That's it. You can refer either [this](http://www.javaworkspace.com/connectdatabase/connectMysql.do) or [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/MySQLJava/article.html) tutorial for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write all the functionality (CRUD operations) yourself. A handy tutorial can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/).